# How to end a session in .net core when a user clicks on sign-out

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, session, cookies

The session.abbandon does not exists anymore.
HttpContext.Session.Clear() does not end the browser session, so in the browser session cookies (cookies with no expiration date) are not deleted.

I need to delete a browser cookie (testcookie) from a certain path

\test\

But the sign out can be done from other pages , which makes the cookie inaccessible.

so making it a session cookie and let the session be terminated seems like a solution

session.abbandon  and try to delete the cookie from a path

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Cookie handler, like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(opt => 
{
  ...
});
```

Then to do a signout, you do this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Do the logout
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    //Important, this method should never return anything.
}
```

if you just want to clear what is in the current session in memory, then you can use:

```
   HttpContext.Session.Clear();
```

I did write a blog post, talking more about the purpose of the session store and how it can improve security at:
[Improving ASP.NET Core Security By Putting Your Cookies On A Diet](https://nestenius.se/2024/01/22/improving-asp-net-core-security-by-putting-your-cookies-on-a-diet/)

Answer (score 0):

If you know any thing about session events try to implement it.

```
Session.Clear();
```

Or

```
Session.RemoveAll();
```

Otherwise, a simple approach would be to keep the userid in a hidden field. When Clicking on Login keep that value in a hidden field. When clicking on logout, remove the value from the hidden field.
Although try to Implement It The session. This Hidden field concept is not up to the mark.